# add a string value to my return page_head string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

not to complex, simply I want to add a string sDtd value to my return page_head string (helper). This is what I have so far. Thanks!!! P

```
public static string WriteDocType(HttpContext context)
{
    string sDtd ="will equal document type!"

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/vnd.wap.wml";        

    String page_head = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"+sDtd+"<wml><head><meta http-equiv=\"Cache-Control\" content=\"max-age=0\" /></head><card title=\"Unsupported\"><p align=\"center\"><br/>Sorry! this mobile web browser is not supported.</p></card></wml>";
    return page_head;
 }
```

Comment: Please don't answer the above comment with "yes, it is not working". What, specifically, is wrong? How can we help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

semicolon needed at the end of the string sDtd instantiation.